# I would like to delete all the contents on my Iphone but the LCD and touch sensitivity is gone. What should I do?

Tags: iphone

I already did a back up before and now I would like to delete all the contents on my iPhone, but the LCD and touch sensitivity accidentally went gone and blacked out. What should I do? Before the exchange of the new Phone from the Phone company to the old broken one. I would appreciate it if someone could teach me on how to delete all the contents. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know what you mean by the LCD and touch sensitivity is "gone", but try this:
- Connect your iPhone to your Computer
- Open **iTunes**
- Select your iPhone
- On the **Overview** Panel select **restore**
- Follow the instructions

I hope it works.